# Flask instance name must be 'application', anything else, like 'app' will fail

Tags: flask, wsgi

I have been working on configuring my Flask web application to run on an Ubuntu machine, to move away from the framework's development server to a production server.

To help me configure WSGI and nginx, I followed this guide posted from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Following the guide, everything works great! Note however in this example, the instance of Flask is named 'application', a bit different than the 'app' that is commonly used almost [everywhere](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (such as on the Flask website and documentation).

Contents of `myflaskapp.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Contents of `wsgi.py`:

```
from weather import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

However, if I were to change the instance names in the above files from 'application' to 'app' I receive an 'Internal Server Error' with nothing in the log file indicating a reason why.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and

```
from myflaskapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

According to the comments in the tutorial posted above, a couple of other users were experiencing the same issues. I can't understand why this particular server requires the name to be 'application' - it's something I can live with, but it just seems odd.

Thanks for any ideas you might be able to provide!

Comment: you're showing `from weather` in one file and `from myfaskapp` in another- why/what's the change here?

Comment: Sorry, it's a copy/paste error from when I copied the code from the tutorial linked above (not from an old copy of the file on my server). Good catch, though, I searched through it a couple of times to make sure I didn't have typos before making my first ever post. Oops :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean uWSGI, it looks for something named `application`. If you'd like to give it a different name, you can specify one in your config:

```
[uwsgi]
callable = app
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see the 'callable' parameter in any of the searching I did, but adding this into my config file it works perfectly. Thank you!